# Issues with lights in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Scene View and Game View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wFgb.jpg)

Using point lights to light up some part of the scene. Well this point light is not showing up in the game view but working in the scene view. I am using URP. How can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit->Project Settings->Quality*. Under the *Rendering* tab, You will see your ***Universal Render Pipeline Asset***. Click on it. In the inspector, Under *Lighting*, You will see ***Per Object Limit***. Bump up that number and that should do it.